# Changing the options in a Datalist with reactJS

Tags: reactjs, html-datalist

I'm trying to update the values in a Datalist when the user type in the input text field, I'm kind of newbie with ReactJS, I tried this code but it is not working:

```
var MyList = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        options: [<option key={'taste'} value={'zeitwert'}>{'Name'}</option>]
    }
},
changeHandler: function(e) {
    console.log('In changeHandler');
    this.state.options.push(
      <option key={'some_key2'} value={'some_value2'}>{'Second Option'}</option>,
      <option key={'some_key3'} value={'some_value3'}>{'Third Option'}</option>
      );
},
render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={this.changeHandler} placeholder="Owner" list="slist" name="owner_id" />
        <datalist id="slist">{this.state.options}</datalist>
      </div>
    )
}
```

});

I'm not getting any error message and the console.log line works fine, but the Second and Third options don't appear in the list.

What I'm doing wrong? thx!

**UPDATE**

This code works:

```
  changeHandler: function(e) {
    console.log('In changeHandler');
    tmp = [];
    tmp.push(
      <option key={'some_key2'} value={'some_value2'}>{'Second Option'}</option>,
      <option key={'some_key3'} value={'some_value3'}>{'Third Option'}</option>
      );
    this.setState({options: tmp});
   },
```

Thanks Ilya!

Answer (score 3):

Just changing the state won't trigger a UI update. You need to tell React that the state has changed by calling `setState` or other functions described here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use `datalist` like `select` via [react-html-datalist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-datalist)